# C++ Program giving false result

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I don't really know why this program isn't working. This is done with the help of pointers. This program counts the number of even integers, but the screen displays: 0 or 1

Here it is...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int evencount(int* x, int y)
{
    int i, even = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++);
    {
        if (*(x + i) % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        }
    }
    return (even);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter size of array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> *(arr + i);
    }
    int num;
    num = evencount(arr, n);
    cout << "Even count=" << num;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[n];` This shouldn't compile as written.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<y;i++);` <-- empty loop (remove semicolon `;`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: This code would be much clearer if it used array indexing directly. Change `*(arr+i)` to `arr[i]` and change `*(x+i)%2` to `x[i]%2`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all look at the loop: `for(i=0;i<y;i++)`**`;`**

Here you have a semicolon **`;`** - this means you've created an empty loop that *does actually nothing* except setting `i` to `y`.

Now this: `if (*(x + i)...` - here `i` is equal to `y` (after previous loop) so you access an array out of bounds (`x[y]` is not valid, valid is only indexes in range [0, x-1]) thus invoking *Undefined Behaviour*.

And as already pointed out in comment to your question by @RyanP one more problem:

`int arr[n];`   <-- this should not compile (unless you use some specific compiler extensions)

To make an array with dynamic size you can do:

1. `int *a = new int[n];`

or better use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for such purposes:

2. `std::vector<int>(n);`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<y;i++);
```

you are doing nothing in this for loop so it is always checking one element. The one in position `y` as `i` will get incremented up to that point by the for loop.
The element in position `y` is thus undefined and out of range which leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: you should probably clarify the reason that this loop does nothing except increment `i` - ie. the `;`.

Comment: No, not a first one, because after initialization it increments it up to and including `y`

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych yep good spot!

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych I have updated my answer but yours is way more detailed than mine. +1 for that.

Answer (score -3):

One of the problems I see is that you are trying to dynamically allocate an array.  In a compiled program, you need to have a fixed allocation of arr.  Try declaring arr as int arr[100].  You can still have the user enter n as the number of entries actually entered.

Comment: It is poor practice to specify arbitrary array sizes in the hopes that they are large enough. I would not encourage it as a solution, rather consider `std::vector` as a standard alternative. Additionally OP is likely using gcc where variable length arrays are supported. While it is a bad idea to rely on this extension, it is not causing his problem.